# How to reach an IP in a VLAN when there is no interface in that VLAN on my server?

Tags: networking, sles, vlan

We have a VLAN_ID that is not in the /etc/sysconfig/networking/ifcfg-* files.

We need to reach an IP from this VLAN.

How can we reach this VLAN if there is no interface on the server with this VLAN?

If I create a new interface on the server with the needed VLAN and it is in the needed VLANs IP range, it works, I can reach it. **But isn't there a better solution**, where I don't need to waste an additional IP from that VLAN?

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can't reach a network unless you have a route to it. This applies whether it's a "normal" network or a VLAN-based one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I create a new interface on the server with the needed VLAN and it is in the needed VLANs IP range, it works, I can reach it.

This implies that the VLANs have non-overlapping IP ranges. In that case, the traditional solution is *routing*. If you have a dedicated router device with connectivity to both VLANs, it could probably easily be configured to allow the traffic you need.

Failing that, if there is a Linux/Unix system that already has connectivity to both VLANs, it could be configured to allow routing between them. But in that case, there is probably a reason why those two VLANs are kept unconnected by routers, and configuring routing on a random host might undermine that reason.

You should talk to your network administrator about your problem before trying anything else: if you configure a host to route traffic between "public" and "secure" networks in an organization that needs to care about those things, it could turn out to have a serious limiting effect on your professional career.

Comment: using a gw with routing helped, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a new network block with a private IP address range you do not have  on top of the existent network and NICs with interface aliases, or configure IPv6/use local-link IPv6 addresses for a quick use.

However, if you plan to use it as a permanent solution, you will add unwarranted maintenance complexity and possible unwanted interactions on the long run.

I would do the proper network planning, and use up an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a LAN segment, VLAN or real, without having an IP in this segment. So there's no way around "wasting" an IP.

And the private IP address ranges are large enough this shouldn't be a problem, and in a pinch you can even use link-local 169.* IP addresses.

Of course you may have to setup the other hosts in this segment correctly to make it work.